# How to get the upload progress when using sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, network-programming, winsock

When downloading a file, I know how much data has been downloaded and so I can show the download progress.

However, when uploading a file, I don't really know how much data has been received by the other end and so I can't show the upload progress, so I'm thinking that the only way to know how much data has been uploaded is by making the receiver send back to me how much data has been received every time some data is received.

Is this correct or is there's another way?

Comment: Just keep track of what you've sent. If absolutely necessary, reduce the socket send buffer. But tracking what you've sent/queued is probably good enough.

Comment: @David Schwartz So I should assume that how much data has been uploaded to be the same as how much data has been sent to the socket send buffer? But this will only give me approximate results and not 100% accurate results (though this won't be a problem if the socket send buffer is only a few kilobytes).

Comment: @user4582812: correct.  For an upload, all you can get is an approximation. Outbound data is queued in the kernel, and your code blocks on that queue only when it is full.  The queue is transmitted in the background. So all you can do is report the progress of how much data you have "sent". The only way to know if the data was actually received on the other end is if the other party sends you an acknowledgement afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting upload you can get how much data to upload. And after that you can calculate how much data you send on each request. From this you can show progress.